# Acceso a la BD desde un Servicio Web

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, app.config

estoy necesitando acceder a la base de datos desde un servicio web, para lo cual dentro de la solucion tengo varios proyectos..  el servicio web, por si solo inicia un timer, el cual ejecuta una accion cada X segundos.
Esta accion, esta dentro de una class library (Business) la cual a su vez accesa una capa DAL (en otra class Library) que accede al a BD.
Usualmente utilizo este esquema, para acceder a los datos en la BD, excepcionalmente en este caso particular, mi interface de usuario es un servicio windows.
Este servicio tiene un archivo App.config, en donde instale el conextionString correspondiente a la BD.
Ya verifique en otro proyecto (winform) que el conectionString esta funcionando (me trae datos de la BD)
Para la instalacion del servicio, genere un instalador en la misma solucion. 
Todo esto compila sin probelas. y el servicio se instala de forma correcta. es mas, cuando lo inicio, me indica que el timer se encuentra funcionando ejecutando cada N segundos la rutina que accede a la BD con el metodo antes descrito.
Mi problema es, que al momento de accede, me aparece (luego de un rato) un mensaje que me indica que no puede acceder a la BD.
Este es el mensaje

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Error relacionado con
>   la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una
>   conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste
>   no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es
>   correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones
>   remotas. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error al
>   buscar el servidor o instancia especificado)

en el app.config tengo la siguiente definicion para el conextionstrig

```html
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="ModelAccuro" connectionString="data source=ZERO-DEV3;initial catalog=CertusAccuro_dev;Persist Security Info=false; pwd=52SP%uEvCj@F0;User ID=accuro; integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--<add name="ModelAccuro" connectionString="data source=ZERO-DEV3;initial catalog=CertusAccuro_dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="ModelAccuro" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-6U3TOS0;initial catalog=CertusAccuro_dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <!--<add name="ModelAccuro" connectionString="data source=DESKTOP-R8F381P\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=CertusAccuro_dev;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
  </connectionStrings>
... resto del app.config
```

Ayuda pls.. estoy hace rato con este lio y no lo puedo resolver. Gracias

Comment: Estas seguro de que desde el equipo desde ejecutas tu servicio web tienes acceso a `DESKTOP-6U3TOS0`?

Comment: Hola Pikoh, gracias por responder. El servicio esta instalado en el mismo equipo. de hecho, lo instalo desde Vs2017

Comment: Esto se debe principalmente a dos cosas, la primer es que tu aplicación no encuentra el servidor de la base de datos a pesar de que estén instalados en el mismo equipo, intenta cambiar `data source=DESKTOP-6U3TOS0;` por `data source=localhost;`. La segunda es que el nombre de la base de datos esté mal escrito, asegúrate de tener el nombre correcto ;)

Comment: He intentado poner LocalHost, o tb la IP del equipo. pero en ningun caso funcina. Flxtr, ya verifique que el ConctionString que estoy usando esta correcto, ya que accedi a la funcion que accede a los datos desde otra aplicacion tipo winform, y si lee correctamente la tabla...  Lo unico extraño que he notado, es que por ejemplo, los tags del segmento appSettings en el mismo app.config, tampoc puiede leelos, es decir, simplemente no los encuientra. voy a eliminar el servicio windows y lo creare nuevamente, por ahi peude ser que sea un problema para acceder al app.config.

Comment: Hice otro ejemplo mas sencillo (accediendo igual a la BD) y al momento de ejecutar no me aparece el mensaje anterior, si no que este otro: System.Data.DataException: An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: No se puede abrir la base de datos "CertusAccuro_dev" solicitada por el inicio de sesión. Error de inicio de sesión.
Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

Comment: en el servicio windows, al agregar el instalador, le estoy indicando en el Account:LocalSystem. Esta bien eso? segun se, es lo que tiene mas privilegios a nivel local.

Comment: El error de `Error de inicio de sesión del usuario 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'` es porque tienes habilitado en tu sql server la autentificacion de windows. Normalmente es mejor usar autenticacion de sql server, para que en cada conexion te pida usuario y contraseña en lugar de que trate de logearse con el usuario de windows activo.

Comment: ok, gracias, tienes razon, el tema de las cuentas de usuario es algo que aun no veo de forma mas exhaustiva, pero ya me quedo claro como funciona. Lo que hice por el momento es darle accesos al usuario NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. voy a investigar como realizar el acceso desde el servicio windows con un usuario y pass diferentes en el connectionString. Gracias